# I just ran about 30' stranded Cat5E through my attic and down a cathedral wall, is this proper?

Tags: home-networking, cable, cat6, cat5e

OK, the company I work for wants me to start working for home. But in order to do so I need a solid connection no wireless, as the VoIP will be using a Meraki router attached to me router. I prefabbed my master bedroom with a 2" x 4" hole and ran a 30'ft stranded patch cord (Non CMR Rated) through the attic and down the wall. Everything is basically complete, as I have a B-Termination on the CAT6 Wall Jack since that seems to be the standard. I tested the connection on my PS4 and was able to establish a solid LAN connection.

Currently, there is nothing either end of the patch cable, as someone on Reddit said I should be using CMR in the attic.

I am here on super user because I am long-time lurker as I use this site for solving problems at the organization I work for, however I spend more time reading issues about powershell. I have seen a lot of valid and logical points made here and I am resorting to your professional opinion as a solution to a matter I am facing.

Comment: Who can say what's proper? Does it look terrible? Are you concerned that it might not meet building codes? Or are you just concerned with functionality?

Comment: Building standard I guess. I just want to make sure its not going to start a fire or if its OK to use the stranded cable of that length within the attic

Comment: I have no idea what the maximum length for CAT5e is in imperial measures... meters, that's something I can work with though...

Comment: To be up to building code? Yes.  Can you get away with just 30ft through your wall? Probably.  Could you be denied a home insurance claim if there's a fire? Maybe.  CMR is more flame resistant.  But, you can get a 30ft cmr cat6 on amazon for under $20. Add 2 Keystone jack inline couplers and you're done.  No messing with termination issues, too much unwrapped wire, etc.  Also, 100M = 328ft for the max length.

Comment: If it is good quality cable properly installed, then there should not be any issue. I have a 50 foot manufactured CAT5e cable with RJ45 ends running from my router in the basement to my Ubiquity box upstairs.  Works great and performance is top, solid and robust.